# Erro de syntax sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer um insert no banco de dados mais estou com um problema de syntax, ainda não consigui identificar o erro.

```
$sql='INSERT INTO tabela   
    (
        nome, 
        nit, 
        rg, 
        cpf, 
    )
    VALUES';

foreach($dados as $linha_bd)
{
$sql=$sql."('"
'".$linha_bd['nome']."',
'".$linha_bd['nit']."',
'".$linha_bd['rg']."',
'".$linha_bd['cpf']."')";
```

}

Comment: Remova a virgula em `cpf,`, para concatenar strings use `.=` no lugar de `=` que faz uma nova atribuição a cada volta do foreach.

Comment: Meu caro, estou com outro problema agora, o erro mudou desta vez, (ï»¿SQL invÃ¡lido: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
'00000439020154036304',
'0006660000',
'MARCOS DE ALMEIDA',
'08782952833',
' at line 44)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova  a virgula após o cpf

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela(nome, nit, rg, cpf,) VALUES ';
 --------------------------------------------^
```

A concatenação aqui está invertida

```
$sql=$sql."('"'".$linha_bd['nome']."','".$linha_bd['nit']."','".$linha_bd['rg']."','".$linha_bd['cpf']."')";
```

errado:

```
$sql."('"'".$linha_bd['nome']."'
-----^   | 
abriu    |  
         |essa aspa simples ficou da concatenação
```

Para eliminar o erro de sintaxe do php pode fazer assim:

```
$sql .= "('{$linha_bd['nome']}'"
```

Outra forma de corrigir o erro de sintaxe com [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), use os parâmentros adequados para cada tipo de dados `%s` é para strings.

```
foreach($arr_entrada as $linha_bd){
    $sql .= sprintf("('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),", $linha_bd['nome'],$linha_bd['nit'], $linha_bd['rg'], $linha_bd['cpf']);
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); //remove a ultima virgula se o objetivo é gerar um insert com varios VALUES
```

[phpfiddle - exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/khxy-n29x)

Comment: Obrigado meu caro, agora está funcionando.